# Create DNS alias

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record, alias

How i can create DNS alias?
ie.: i have one domain named `example.com` and second domain - `example.net`. Zone-file of first domain contents:

> `example.com. IN A 10.1.2.3
>
>   www.example.com. IN A 10.1.2.3
>
>   *.example.com IN CNAME example.com.`

What should i write to second's domain zone-file, that redirected from `http://www.example.net` to `http://www.example.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dns does not handle http redirection.. You can just cname example.net to example.com just fine.. but you would have to do the redirect on your webserver side

Comment: There is an example of what you want to do on Super User [**here**](http://superuser.com/questions/122810/apache-redirect-from-one-domain-to-another-domain)